# How to use PyOpenCl passing arguments to kernel

Tags: python, opencl, pyopencl

I wrote a python code to generate the mandelbrot set to a ppm file, and now I'm trying to implement pyopencl to speed up the process and compare running times but I'm very unaware of how pyopencl works in some ways and all the research I've made has not helped me in this case. So my kernel function looks like this:

```
__kernel void mandelbrot(__global const float* real, __global const float* imaginary,
                        __global const float* max_iterations, __global int* output) 
{
    int gid = get_global_id(0);

    float rx = *real;
    float iy = *imaginary;

    float x = 0.0f;
    float y = 0.0f;
    int iterations = 0;

    while( (iterations < max_iterations) &&  ((x*x) + (y*y) < 4.0f)) {
        float temp = x*x - y*y + real;
        y = 2.0 * x * y + imaginary;
        x = temp;
        iterations++;
    }
}
```

And my input variables look like this:

```
real_gpu = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf = np.float32(realVal))
imag_gpu = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf = np.float32(imagVal))
output = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY, width * height * np.dtype(np.float64).itemsize)

prg = cl.Program(ctx, string_parallelism).build()
mandelbrot = prg.mandelbrot
mandelbrot.set_scalar_arg_dtypes([np.float64, np.float64, np.float64, None])

globalrange = (width, height)
localrange = None
mandelbrot(queue, globalrange, localrange, real_gpu, imag_gpu, maxN, output)
```

When running my code, it produces this error:

```
CompilerWarning: From-source build succeeded, but resulted in non-empty logs:
Build on <pyopencl.Device 'Pitcairn' on 'AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing' at 0x56229da25400> succeeded, but said:

"/tmp/OCL3291941T1.cl", line 13: warning: operand types are incompatible ("int"
          and "const __global float *")
      while( (iterations < max_iterations) &&  ((x*x) + (y*y) < 4.0f)) {
                         ^


  warn(text, CompilerWarning)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tei/tei2020/rodrigues17193tei/hpc2/pyopencl_mandelbrot/paralell_mandelbrot.py", line 93, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/tei/tei2020/rodrigues17193tei/hpc2/pyopencl_mandelbrot/paralell_mandelbrot.py", line 71, in main
    mandelbrot(queue, globalrange, localrange, real_gpu, imag_gpu, maxN, output)
  File "<generated code>", line 12, in enqueue_knl_mandelbrot
RuntimeError: when processing arg#1 (1-based): Unable to cast Python instance to C++ type (compile in debug mode for details)
```

What changes do I need to make in the variables so my kernel can execute properly?

Answer (score 1):

There is no information for type of `maxN` but I will assume that is `int` because `float` does not make sense.

The problem is that kernel parameter for `max_iterations` is `__global const float*` which requires buffer to be created on the host side. Passing this as a buffer also does not make any sense.

So I would suggest changing `max_iterations` type to `int`, like that:

```
kernel void mandelbrot(__global const float* real, __global const float* imaginary,
                        int max_iterations, __global int* output)
{
 .....
}
```

Then pass it to kernel like that:

```
mandelbrot(queue, globalrange, localrange, real_gpu, imag_gpu, np.int32(maxN), output)
```

Comment: The traceback error has changed but still points out something wrong about the first argument. I dont know if it referes to the queue or the realVal variable. Error code shows: "pyopencl._cl.LogicError: Kernel.set_arg failed: INVALID_VALUE - when processing arg#1 (1-based): invalid kernel argument"

Comment: Try to comment out line starting with `mandelbrot.set_scalar_arg_dtypes`

Comment: It now gives me the error "Job 1 was terminated by signal SIGSEGV (Address boundary error)". I think this means everything works fine and theres some problem with the machine itself. I say this because while I was using OpenMP it gave out the same error when I tried using more than 4 threads, but everything would be ok if i used 4 or less threads